# How can I use Tor proxy to hide my website IP address in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, proxy, configuration, ip, tor

My webserver is Nginx. I want to hide my server IP address using Tor proxy so my server IP address will be hidden. What Nginx configuration can I use to do it?

Comment: It sounds like you want to create a `.onion` site.  I don't think what you are asking is possible otherwise.  [this](https://www.bentasker.co.uk/documentation/security/290-hosting-tor-hidden-services-onions) question might be helpful for that.

Comment: No. I want to hide my server IP so it cannot be obtained by `host mydomain.com` command. I want to use Tor proxy to hide it.

Comment: @man I think you can do that with Nginx rules alone, by using a proxy that forwards traffic to your real ip address and masks it to public. Tor hidden services and proxies imply a `.onion` TLD, but I would love to be proven wrong on this.